# Enterprise library manage connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, enterprise-library

I am building an application with c# and I decided to use the Enterprise Library for the DAL (SQL Server).

I don't remember where, but I had read an article about EntLib which said that the connections are closed automatically.

Is it true?

If not, what is the best approach of managing the connections in the middle layer? 
Open and close in each method?

The above is a sample method of how I am using the EntLib

```
public DataSet ReturnSomething
{
    var sqlStr = "select something";
    DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlStr);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param1", SqlDbType.BigInt, hotelID);
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, date);
    return db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

the ExecuteDataSet method returns a DataSet object that contains all the data. This gives you your own local copy. The call to ExecuteDataSet opens a connection, populates a DataSet, and closes the connection before returning the result

for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648933.aspx

Comment: What about if I want to get a DataReader or Insert, delete, update? How the connection will be handled?

Comment: hello @Massimiliano Peluso I wanted to keep the connection open until I manually don't want to close it. So what can we do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have something like a static class used as a Façade which would provide the correct connection for your library subsystems.

```
public static class SystemFacade {
    // Used as a subsystem to which the connections are provided.
    private static readonly SystemFactory _systemFactory = new SystemFactory();

    public static IList<Customer> GetCustomers() {
        using (var connection = OpenConnection(nameOfEntLibNamedConnection))
            return _systemFactory.GetCustomers(connection);
    }

    public static DbConnection OpenConnection(string connectionName) {
        var connection = 
            // Read EntLib config and create a new connection here, and assure
            // it is opened before you return it.

        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        return connection;            
    }
}

internal class SystemFactory {
    internal IList<Customer> GetCustomers(DbConnection connection) {
        // Place code to get customers here.
    }
}
```

And using this code:

```
public class MyPageClass {
    private void DisplayCustomers() {
        GridView.DataSource = SystemFacade.GetCustomers();
    }
}
```

In this code sample, you have a static class that provides the functionalities and features of a class library. The Façade class is used to provide the user with all possible action, but you don't want to get a headache with what connection to use, etc. All you want is the list of customers out of the underlying datastore. Then, a call to `GetCustomers` will do it.

The Façade is an "intelligent" class that knows where to get the information from, so creates the connection accordingly and order the customers from the subsystem factory. The factory does what it is asked for, take the available connection and retrieve the customers without asking any further questions.

Does this help?

Comment: So the article I had read was wrong and I must close and open the connection for each use! Thanks for your help Will Marcouiller

Comment: No, you don't need to manually manage connections - the block will open and close connections for you automatically. This solution is overkill, especially if you're using datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, EntLib closes connections for you (actually it releases them back into the connection pool). That is the main reason why we originally started to use EntLib.

However, for all new development we have now gone on to use Entity Framework, we find that much more productive.

Comment: All this transparency makes me worry. So, I don't have to open the connection neither close it. When I perform a new "action" it gets the available connection from pooling (if available) or it opens a new connection? I execute sp_who2 in the DB and there have more than 15 connections with sleeping status. I am the only user who uses this db, so I think that the number of available connection is too much.

Comment: Yes is all automatic, try putting your code in a loop and run it 1000 times. The number of connections should not go up.

Comment: that's weird, something is going wrong cause as I said before I had more than 15 connections. It seems that it doesn't close the connections and on every demand creates a new one.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the datareader. I'll try to check the connection with dataset instead of datareader.

Comment: It sounds like you're leaking DataReaders. Are you calling db.ExecuteReader() inside a using block, or closing the datareader afterwards? The connection stays open until you do so.

Comment: Yes I do like dataReaders. I am closing the datareader afterwards. I tried to use dataSet instead of datareaders and the connections where recycled as a charm. So I think that the problem comes somehow from datareader